# std::set filled with boost::variant elements cannot be sorted descendantly?

Tags: c++, boost

```
typedef boost::variant<long long,double,string> possibleTypes ;

set<possibleTypes,less<possibleTypes> > ascSet ;
set<possibleTypes,greater<possibleTypes> > descSet ;
```

When I try to compile I get a bunch of errors in some library headers.
But, if I remove the third line (the one with `descSet` ) the code compile just fine.

What's the problem? Can't boost::variant objects be sorted in descendant order??

**Edit:**
I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and Boost 1.38.0 and the following command line:

```
cl /EHsc /I"C:\boost_1_38_0" test.cpp
```

**Edit2**
As it was suggested, by Doug T, if I define this:

```
bool operator>(const possibleTypes& a, const possibleTypes& b){
   return b < a ;
}
```

Then the following code doesn't compile:

```
possibleTypes pt1="a", pt2="b" ;
greater<possibleTypes> func ;   
cout << func(pt1,pt2) << endl ;
```

However, this code compiles just fine:

```
possibleTypes pt1="a", pt2="b" ;
cout << (pt1 > pt2) << endl ;
```

Could anyone help me to understand why??

I tried with VC++ 2005 and GCC 3.4.6

Comment: Which version of Boost are you using? I just tried your code with 1.38.0 and VC++ 9.0 and it compiled without any issues.

Comment: Why have two sets? Why not have just one and use a reverse iterator when you need descending order?

Comment: Really? It must be the copiler version (I just updated my post)

Comment: Can you provide at least the first error messages? I.e. the ones about the declaration itself, not the ones that result from descSet being improperly defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested, if I define this:

```
bool operator>(const possibleTypes& a, const possibleTypes& b){
   return b < a ;
}
```

Then the following code doesn't compile:

```
possibleTypes pt1="a", pt2="b" ;
greater<possibleTypes> func ;   
cout << func(pt1,pt2) << endl ;
```

However, this code compiles just fine:

```
possibleTypes pt1="a", pt2="b" ;
cout << (pt1 > pt2) << endl ;
```

Could anyone help me to understand why??

I tried with VC++ 2005 and GCC 3.4.6

Comment: Try defining operator> in namespace boost:  namespace boost { bool operator>(const possibleTypes& a, const possibleTypes& b) ... }.  The compiler's looking in the wrong place for the operator>, although personally I would expect it to look at any operator> taking two possibleType arguments.

Comment: Nope - Argument-dependent lookup. It's not going to search everywhere, it looks in the namespace of the caller (std::greater) and the namespace of the arguments (boost::variant). In the second case, the namespace of the caller is (probably) the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks, Max. The problem was fixed adding operator> to the boost namespace.
And thanks, MSalters, for clarifying the rules.

Answer (score 3):

It appears a < operator is defined for boost::variant but not a > operator. Thus perhaps std::less<> works but not std::greater<>

See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html)

I would try defining a a free > operator.

```
bool operator > (boost::variant<...> lhs, boost::variant<..> rhs)
{
    return (rhs < lhs) // thanks Chris Jester Young
}
```

Comment: Why not just: return rhs < lhs

Comment: yeah that would be simpler, wouldn't it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the greater operator available. If *possibleTypes* does not provide one, you can either define a free one like Doug suggested or try to use [Boost operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/utility/operators.htm).